# ng-repeat in other ng-repeat is not working

Tags: angularjs

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "NAME",
    "tests": [
      {
        "testname": "abc",
        "relatedResource": [
          {
            "accessType": "fttb",
          },
          {
            "accessType": "fttn",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "testname": "xyz",
        "relatedResource": [
          {
            "accessType": "fttp",
          },
          {
            "accessType": "fttp",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.data=response.data.tests;  

<div ng-repeat="l in data">
    <div ng-repeat="i in l.relatedResource">
        {{i.accessType}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question to show the actual HTML code using `ng-repeat`, along ideally with the corresponding code from the controller.

Comment: I am able to iterate data with single ng-repeat. But i need the the array of objects which are located at relatedResources .

Comment: its working fine right i can see the output in my plunker as                      fttb
fttn
fttp
fttp

Comment: understand the hierarchy, `relatedResource` is inside `tests`

Comment: I actually don't see a problem with how you are using the hierarchy.  There must be some other issue with your code.

Comment: @MaheshbabuNeeli : try my answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305425/6608101

Answer (score 0):

try this, you need multiple `ng-repeat` to access `relatedResource`

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/9075/) I printed the output

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">
  {{val.name}}
      <div ng-repeat="test in val.tests">
                    - {{test.testname}}
           <div ng-repeat="resource in test.relatedResource">
                    - -{{resource.accessType}}
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
  "data": {
    "name": "NAME",
    "tests": [
      {
        "testname": "abc",
        "relatedResource": [
          {
            "accessType": "fttb",
          },
          {
            "accessType": "fttn",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "testname": "xyz",
        "relatedResource": [
          {
            "accessType": "fttp",
          },
          {
            "accessType": "fttp",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in data">
    <span ng-repeat="val in obj.tests">
      {{val.testname}}
      <span ng-repeat="v in val.relatedResource">
        {{v.accessType}}
      </span>
      <br/>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually not much information about the question.

If you receive the json-data from a remote server, you should always check and convert it to a real json-object.

You can simply use

```
$scope.data = response.data.tests;

$scope.getData = function() 
{
   return angular.toJson($scope.data);
}
```

or you can test it with:

```
{{data | json}}
```