# How to iterate the Array consists of Array

Tags: angularjs

```
[
    {
        "key":"ntd",
        "value":
            [
                ["a","b","c"],
                ["x","y","z"],
            ]
    }
 ]
```

I want to iterate the above JSON in ng-repeat and to print as ["a","b","c"] , ["x","y","z"]

```
<div ng-repeat="r in value.value">
   //code goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Not getting what exactly you're having. verify https://jsonlint.com here and then ask.

Comment: @Maheshbalu Neeli 
Try my answer on this question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305425/6608101

Comment: Yes, its working.... Thank you

Comment: If any answers helps you then reward it. That will encourage the people to helps you more and more.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simply like below by using nested `ng-repeat`'s

```
<div ng-repeat="r in data">
   <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in r.value">
      Key: {{r.key}}
      <div ng-repeat="v in value">
         {{v}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/a7AgI1Bc3OZ5g3O4vIsk?p=preview)